# How to limit the result of query with a join?

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my database:

*categories*

```
id
category
message
```

*messages*

```
id
title
message
```

I am trying to retrieve two messages with their categories. Every message can have multiple categories. I've tried with the following query:

```
SELECT categories.category, messages.id, messages.title, messages.message
FROM categories
RIGHT JOIN messages
ON messages.id = category.message
ORDER BY messages.id DESC
LIMIT 2
OFFSET 0
```

The ouput for this is something like:

```
category   id   title        message
test-cat   1    Test title   This is the message body
category2  1    Test title   This is the message body
```

However this query results in only two rows (because the message which is retrieved has multiple categories). How can I limit on the number of messages rather than the number of categories? So that the result is like:

```
category   id   title        message
test-cat   1    Test title   This is the message body
category2  1    Test title   This is the message body
test-cat   2    Another msg  This is content
test-cat2  2    Another msg  This is content
something  2    Another msg  This is content
```

Comment: Use "select distinct" or "group by": http://www.sqlteam.com/article/how-to-use-group-by-with-distinct-aggregates-and-derived-tables

Comment: Doesn't `distinct` make sure I get only 1 result of each item?

Comment: Yes, exactly, if you want only one category/message, or one message/category.  Which is what I thought you were asking...

Comment: What I need is a resultset like at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the limit in a subquery:

```
SELECT categories.category, m.id, m.title, m.message
FROM categories RIGHT JOIN
     (select *
      from messages
      ORDER BY messages.id DESC
      limit 2
     ) m
     ON m.id = categories.message
ORDER BY m.id DESC
```

Comment: I get an error when trying to use that :( `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "m" LINE 1: ...M categories RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * from messages ORDER BY m.id DESC ... ^`

Comment: I mistyped the name of categories as "category".  Should be ok now.

Comment: I've edited your answer and changed the `m.id` inside the subquery to `messages.id` which is working now. Thanks for your help!